Подзапрос выдаёт не совсем то, что нужно
Изучаю подзапросы.
Как ни пытался, на выходе получаю не совсем то, что мне нужно, либо пустоту.
-- В таблице orders хранятся заказы пользователей, а в users непосредственно сами покупатели.
-- Получите информацию о покупателях, которые сделали самый дорогой заказ.
-- Заказов с максимальной стоимостью может быть несколько, а значит и покупателей может быть несколько.
-- Учитывайте только завершенные заказы.
-- Данные отсортируйте по id покупателей.
                                        **orders**  




id
user_id
date
amount
status




1
3
2014-01-23 17:04:04
4500
completed


2
1
2014-03-12 12:12:43
700
completed


3
10
2014-12-31 08:53:25
1240
new


4
7
2015-01-04 18:23:09
500
completed


5
1
2015-01-04 18:25:27
8700
cancelled


6
4
2015-01-12 09:23:14
1350
completed


7
10
2015-01-14 17:16:39
600
new


8
1
2015-02-01 13:32:17
680
completed


9
3
2014-02-16 14:44:05
1400
completed


10
5
2015-02-28 02:00:47
4300
cancelled


11
10
2015-03-12 08:30:23
8000
completed


12
2
2015-04-01 13:04:47
980
completed


13
2
2015-04-14 23:21:25
1600
completed


14
3
2015-04-15 04:17:11
8000
completed


15
7
2015-04-16 08:21:37
8000
new



                         **users**  




id
first_name
last_name
age




1
Вероника
Петрова
20


2
Светлана
Иванова
17


3
Елена
Абрамова
18


4
Василиса
Кац
15


5
Алёна
Сорокина
22


6
Алёна
Федькова
28


7
Лиана
Сорокина
21


8
Карина
Белая
30


9
Анастасия
Дейчман
16


10
Юлия
Фёдорова
25



В результате должны быть только id 3 и 10, но у меня выстреливает ещё и юзер под 7 номером со статусом "new". Не могу понять, почему? Как исправить? Вот, что я делал
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM orders
    WHERE amount = (
        SELECT MAX(amount)
        FROM orders
        WHERE status = 'completed'
        )
)
ORDER BY id   


посмотреть на таблицы с данными и убедиться, что там действительно все так как в вопросе. ибо запрос корректный.

данные я не менял, копировал -> вставил.
Если просто глянуть на таблицу, то 7-я явно не должна входить в список пользователей с завершёнными заказами

беру свои слова назад, запрос кривой. Вам не только цену максимальную надо найти  среди завершеных заказов, но и id юзеров тоже вытащить для максимальной цены И завершенного статуса

Всё оказалось намного проще. Всего-то в выборке по user_id также нужно было указать status = 'completed':
SELECT *   
FROM users  
WHERE id IN (  
    SELECT user_id  
    FROM orders  
    WHERE status = 'completed' AND amount IN (  
        SELECT MAX(amount)  
        FROM orders  
        WHERE status = 'completed'  
        )  
)  
ORDER BY id

На выходе получаю юзеров 3 и 7.
